# Symbolicate crash log with Quincy Kit, give me this error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, symbolicatecrash

i'm trying to symbolicate a crash log using the Quincy Kit, all works fine, but i receive this warning/error in the terminal during the symbolcating:

```
/Applications/Xcode5-DP5.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: file: /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation does not contain architecture: armv7
Can't understand the output from otool ( -> xcrun -sdk iphoneos otool -arch armv7 -l '/Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation')
/Applications/Xcode5-DP5.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: file: /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices does not contain architecture: armv7
Can't understand the output from otool ( -> xcrun -sdk iphoneos otool -arch armv7 -l '/Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices')
/Applications/Xcode5-DP5.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: file: /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit does not contain architecture: armv7
Can't understand the output from otool ( -> xcrun -sdk iphoneos otool -arch armv7 -l '/Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit')
/Applications/Xcode5-DP5.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: file: /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore does not contain architecture: armv7
Can't understand the output from otool ( -> xcrun -sdk iphoneos otool -arch armv7 -l '/Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore')
/Applications/Xcode5-DP5.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: file: /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore does not contain architecture: armv7
Can't understand the output from otool ( -> xcrun -sdk iphoneos otool -arch armv7 -l '/Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore')
/Applications/Xcode5-DP5.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: file: /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib does not contain architecture: armv7
Can't understand the output from otool ( -> xcrun -sdk iphoneos otool -arch armv7 -l '/Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib')
/Applications/Xcode5-DP5.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: file: /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib does not contain architecture: armv7
Can't understand the output from otool ( -> xcrun -sdk iphoneos otool -arch armv7 -l '/Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib')
/Applications/Xcode5-DP5.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: file: /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib does not contain architecture: armv7
Can't understand the output from otool ( -> xcrun -sdk iphoneos otool -arch armv7 -l '/Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib')
/Applications/Xcode5-DP5.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: file: /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib does not contain architecture: armv7
Can't understand the output from otool ( -> xcrun -sdk iphoneos otool -arch armv7 -l '/Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib')
/Applications/Xcode5-DP5.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: file: /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation does not contain architecture: armv7
Can't understand the output from otool ( -> xcrun -sdk iphoneos otool -arch armv7 -l '/Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation')
/Applications/Xcode5-DP5.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: file: /Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib does not contain architecture: armv7
Can't understand the output from otool ( -> xcrun -sdk iphoneos otool -arch armv7 -l '/Users/Piero/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib')
  Sending symbolicated data back to the server ...

  Deleting temporary files ...

Done
```

there is way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You local iOS 6.1.3 symbols only have the data from devices with the armv7s CPU. You need to connect a device with an armv7 CPU and iOS 6.1.3 to Xcode so it can import the symbols from that CPU architecture as well.

You can verify the architectures available in the symbols using `dwarfdump` in a terminal window like:

```
`dwarfdump --uuid "/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.1.3 (10B329)/Symbols/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib"'
```

This should show a UUID for each provided CPU architecture.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, fortunately i have a device with armv7, but if i haven't it there isn't another way to do it? i have to own a lot of device in this way :)

Comment: Only hope is that Apple provides the symbols with Xcode, which usually happens with new Xcode versions. But it doesn't happen for iOS versions that don't change anything in the API/SDK where also no Xcode update is provided. You don't need to have a lot of devices, only one for each CPU architecture and everything later including the iPhone 3GS have either armv7 or armv7s.

Comment: @Kerni I'm too have this issue. I downloaded latest version, but this'snt helped. I can't reproduce a crash report, because crash from other people and how i can resolve this? Thanks

Comment: @CReaTuS I am sorry, but your text doesn't make any sense to me. The original question here is answered. If you have a problem, post a new question with proper details.

Comment: @Kerni I just don't understand, what i'm must to do, if i got a crashreport with build from AppStore. And what i'm must to do with XCode? Can you please explain with steps. Thanks

Comment: @CReaTuS: how about creating a new question or at least searching for similar questions. You will not get an answer to a new question posted as a comment.

Comment: @Kerni My question is will similar of this. Logs and situation is similar, but i don't understand a solution.